# Visual Studio ReSharper Keymap for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, resharper, keymapping

I primarily use Visual Studio and ReSharper (R#) for development and have excellent working knowledge of R#. I want to leverage that knowledge in IntelliJ IDEA (with my personal Java adventures) without having to learn the IDEA keymap scheme. IDEA has a Visual Studio keymap but that mainly updates such key bindings as Find (Ctrl + F) and Replace (Ctrl + H) etc. Because Visual Studio doesn't have built-in capabilities like "Inspect This..." etc. (the kinda stuff provided by R#), those IntelliJ keybinding in Visual Studio keymap are merely a dump of IDEA's.

In VS.NET, ReSharper comes with two keymaps, IDEA and Visual Studio. I've been using the Visual Studio keymap since R# 5 and really would like to have a keymap in IntelliJ idea that actually is a combination of the Visual Studio IDEA keymap and R# Visual Studio keymap. This combinational keymap is what I am calling Visual Studio ReSharper (R#) keymap for IntelliJ IDEA.

I'd appreciate if someone can share thier keymap if they have created one that's close to the stated description. If JetBrains is hearing, how about bundling an additional keymap scheme with IntelliJ that's essentially a combination of Visual Studio scheme (in IntelliJ IDEA) and ReSharper Visual Studio scheme (in VS.NET)?

Comment: And while you enjoy the *alternative* solution, you can upvote here the request to add it as a feature in intellij: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100945

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes, JetBrains is hearing. )
I'll pass your suggestion over to the IntelliJ team. Not sure how it goes from there but it's worth a try.

Comment: OK, @hhariri already released a "first" version of R#-based keymap for IntelliJ for OSX (should work on Windows as well). So this new R#-based keymap for IntelliJ IDEA is cooking in JetBrains labs apparently. That's sooner than I expected, kudos! https://twitter.com/#!/hhariri/statuses/138920149263728640

Comment: We'll most likely include this bundled at some point so any feedback appreciated.

Comment: @HadiHariri: Is there any news about this feature?

Comment: You can download it from here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3569762/resharper.jar. We're working on including it but can't say when that will happen yet.

Comment: It works great, thanks! In case it also wasn't obvious to anyone else, you download resharper.jar and choose it in "Import Settings" in the File menu.

Comment: Found it at https://github.com/hhariri/Tidbits/blob/master/resharper.jar (view Raw to download).  How to use it: http://hadihariri.com/2012/02/17/the-kotlin-journey-part-i-getting-things-set-up/

Comment: It's now on GitHub as Damian mentions https://github.com/hhariri/Tidbits/blob/master/resharper.jar
Sorry for broken link

Comment: Support for Visual Studio key bindings was added to IntelliJ a while ago, see my answer.

Comment: See the answer by @Contango below -- the Visual Studio keymap is now bundled as part of IntelliJ.

Answer (score 14):

As a summary from the comments:

- Download the [jar-file that contains the appropriate keymap and UI-settings](https://github.com/hhariri/Tidbits/blob/master/resharper.jar)
- [Follow these instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/exporting-and-importing-settings.html): File > Import Settings... > Select downloaded jar file.

Also works in Android Studio, as it is IntelliJ-based.

Answer (score 4):

This was completed a while ago!

`IntelliJ 15.0.6` now has built in support for Visual Studio key bindings, see:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Configure+Keymap

[image]

The keyboard bindings are not 100% complete, I tend to add remaining keyboard bindings manually as I discover differences.

Comment: Problem is, they are completely different from the shortcuts that we are used to in ReSharper. :-(