# IntellijIdea resharper keymap

Tags: intellij-idea, keymapping

I recently started with java development using IntellijIDEA (version 12). Since I come from MS world I am used to resharper shortcuts(The visual studio keymap). Is there any way of using the same set of shortcuts in IntellijIDEA? I found a similar question on stackoverflow ([Visual Studio ReSharper Keymap for IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022665/visual-studio-resharper-keymap-for-intellij-idea)) but the proposed solutions do not work(I guess becouse of the newer version).

Uros

Comment: Intellij IDEA includes a Visual Studio keymap (Settings/Keymap, choose 'Visual Studio' from keymaps list) - have you tried it?

Comment: Yes i did try that but it is not the same as resharper's visual studio key map.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio ReSharper Keymap for IntelliJ IDEA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022665/visual-studio-resharper-keymap-for-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 0):

You can install plugin if it is not appear in keymap section by default(step 2).

1. Go to IntelijIdea Preferences -> plugins and type Visual Studio keymap, ReSharper Keymap
   [image]
   [image]
2. You would be able to select visual studio(ReSharper) keymap in preferences -> keymap
   [image]

Screenshots based on IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 (Ultimate Edition)
I would recommend to use the latest version of IntelliJ if it is possible.