# How can Visual Studio shortcut keys be used in Android Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, android-studio, settings, keyboard-shortcuts

I am very familiar with the Visual Studio IDE, and am new to working with Android Studio. Is there a way to configure Android Studio so that the keyboard shortcuts that I'm used to from Visual Studio can be used in Android Studio?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

### For newer Android Studio Versions

*This approach works on at least Android Studio v1.3 and later* (per @Dazzibao's comment)

From the menu, select File | Settings. Select the `Keymap` option on the left, then from the `Keymaps` drop-down, select "Visual Studio". The defined shortcuts are then updated to Visual Studio settings.

Further customizations are able to be made, and applied. To export these settings, from the menu, choose File | Export Settings, and then select *Key Maps*, select a file, and save. These can be restored via File | Import Settings in the same way.

Note: Many of the shortcut keys that I was used to using C# are not set to be the same values using this method. Try the second approach (below) if not satisfied with Android Studio's "Visual Studio" key map assignments.

### For older Android Studio Versions

The same approach has been documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022665/visual-studio-resharper-keymap-for-intellij-idea) for the IntelliJ IDE, and also works for Android Studio. It involves downloading a .jar settings file intended for Resharper users, and importing it into Android Studio.

1. Navigate to: https://github.com/hhariri/Tidbits/blob/master/resharper.jar
2. Click "View Raw" to download the resharper.jar file
3. In Android Studio, import the settings: `File -> Import Settings -> <fullPathTo>/resharper.jar`

Keyboard shortcuts are now as they would be in Visual Studio. For example, from the Run menu, review the debug control flow shortcuts:

[image]

Comment: I do confirm the section "For older Android Studio Versions" is the most effective way to have it works!

Comment: And how about vice-versa?